# How to get Facebook friends email address using Facebook C# sdk 5.4.1.0 in Windows phone 7

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to import Facebook contacts(Friends email address) to using an Windows Phone application app and save those contact to local phone.

I want use Facebook C# sdk for, please tell me how to accomplish this in Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but Facebook doesn't allows export of Friend's email address. The same is mentioned in the note at [Email Permission's](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/email-permissions/) documentation.

> There is no way for apps to obtain email addresses for a user's friends.

If you still want to obtain those Email Ids of User's friend, you would need to send them all [app request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/) to try your application so that you may retrieve those per user basis.

Comment: Thanks Anvesh, I know that FB don't provide freind's email address. I'm looking for an alternate....., you said about "send app request" which is lengthy process.

Comment: @ShapurjatShapurjat Although its a lengthy process but it allows you to achieve what you want.

Comment: @AnveshSaxena how can I get the user's primary email address?

Comment: @anonshankar to get the current user's primary email address you need to get [permission[(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0) from the user.